# Geocoding uses mapquest provider

Tags: api, geocode

I'am using Mapquest provider to work with geocoder but when I use postman to test my API it's shown like this

```
 "error": "Status is REQUEST_DENIED. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"
```

while I did not use any services of google
p/s: I've already provided API key
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just importing your keys and provider from other file, try to put the API-KEY directly like this

FROM THIS

```
const options = {
   provider: process.env.GEOCODER_PROVIDER,
   httpAdapter: 'https',
   apiKey: process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY,
   formatter: null
}
```

TO THIS

```
const options = {
   provider: 'mapquest',
   httpAdapter: 'https',
   apiKey: 'apikey',
   formatter: null
}
```

OR

check your middleware positions if youre using .env put it at the top of the middlewares